# python setup path problem

Tags: python, installation

**

```
cd Python-2.5.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python2.5
make
make test
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/python2.5/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.5
```

**

I followed the above steps to download python 2.5 on Obuntu where python 2.6 was already installed.

Then I changed one the file and tried to install it with the following below command and got an error. Please tell me where I am making the mistake??

```
ankit@ubuntu:~/Desktop/cherrypy$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
copying cherrypy/lib/cptools.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/cherrypy/lib
error: could not delete 'build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/cherrypy/lib/cptools.py': Permission denied
```

When I use d Python 2.5 setup.py install- it gives me this error:

```
ankit@ubuntu:~/Desktop/cherrypy$ python2.5 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build/lib
error: could not create 'build/lib': Permission denied
```

I am using windows and running Ubuntu as an application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the build process created some files with root ownership when you ran this:

```
sudo make install
```

When running as a non-root user, you don't have permission to delete those files.
You may need to run this if you want to be able to build as a non-root user again:

```
sudo make clean
```

Comment: yes, when I try to go into the root directory, it wont let me to go in. It says"permission denied". How Do I get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `python2.5 setup.py install` with root access.

Try `sudo python2.5 setup.py install`

Also, when installing python on a system with other versions of pytho, you should use:

```
sudo make altinstall
```

It installs python to it's own directory creating the appropriate symlinks.

Refer to http://docs.python.org/using/unix.html#on-linux for more info on this.

Comment: I dont have the root acces. Where Do I get the root access? I mean ..what commands??

Comment: if you use `sudo` you'll have root access. Try running the command `sudo python2.5 setup.py install`